# Is there a way to use urllib to open one site until a specified object in it?

Tags: python, windows, urllib

I'm using urllib to open one site and get some information on it.

Is there a way to "open" this site only to the part I need and discard the rest (discard I mean don't open/load the rest)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you are simply trying to parse the site to find the useful "information", then I recommend using the library [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  That library makes it easy to keep certain parts of the site while discarding the rest.

If however you trying to save download bandwidth by downloading only a piece of the site, then you will need to do a lot more work. If that is the case please say so in your question and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read(bytes) instead of read(), this will read a number of bytes instead of all of it. Then append to already downloaded bytes, and see if it contains what you're looking for. Then you should be able to stop download with .close().